# Can I patch arbitrary apps to add Speak Text accessibility to macOS apps that don’t support it?

Tags: macos, accessibility, text-to-speech

In many (if not, most) Mac apps that display or edit text, you can select text and have it spoken out loud, via a right-click or the Edit menu:

[image]

**Note:** I am aware of the Accessibility setting that assigns a keyboard shortcut to speak text… but it doesn't always behave as you'd expect and sometimes reads text from the page that is not highlighted.

Some apps that you would expect to have this ability, don't… which is a pretty big accessibility issue for lots of folks (myself included).

Is there any way to forcibly get this functionality into uncooperative apps?

Comment: can you give a particular app for example?

Comment: Rather than an app-specific approach, how about a script/workflow with an assigned keyboard command that grabs your selected text, copies it into a text-to-speech capable app (Notes?), selects it, and invokes text-to-speech, then closes when you hit escape or some other key? Might even work with macOS's new ability to detect text in images. Oy, now I'm going to have to make time to try this - unless someone else runs with it first...

Answer (score 1):

MacOS provides various functions for apps to use. One of these is called [NSTextView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextview), which provides an interface area for writing and editing text.

So the app developer just tells macOS to create a textview in a window, and the OS will then provide all kinds of services, like Font handling, Cut-and-Paste, and Text-to-Speech automatically.

However, if the developer doesn't use NSTextView, but a different process for creating a text area, then they don't get access to all the other goodies, unless they explicitly provide them.

This is often the case with apps that are written for Windows and Mac, and/or Linux, as these apps tend to rely on cross-platform code libraries.

Your only hope is to contact the developers and ask them to provide accessibility support, if they can with the APIs that they are using.

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is no.

The more complex answer, is that it usually depends on the accessibility of the app. If an app doesn’t use the proper accessibility labels and APIs, it won’t work properly with other assistive technologies like voiceover and speak screen. A classic example of this not working is in an image